# views pager showing X results per page

Tags: views, search, paging

I was wondering if anyone knew how to go about adding a drop down or even a list of links to help change the amount of views results per page.

Ideally, when there's a lot of results you would want to be able to choose:

- 5 per page
- 10 per page
- 20 per page
- 50 per page

A drop down box would be brilliant for this; it is the sort of thing you see on many search forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Steven Ward's site](http://www.wardontheweb.com/selectable-items-per-page-hack-for-drupal-6-views/) for a bit of a hacky way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I actually saw this moments after posting. However, I have got several GET variables in my URL and I have no idea how to append to them without getting rid of them completely

for example: /search?region=london&type=offce

Would need to be: /search?region=london&type=offce&items-to-display=10

Instead his code will just give me /search?items-to_display=10

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, silly me!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now built into Views 3.

Comment: How do you do this with Views 3?

Comment: At Pager > choose one of the Paged options, then in the settings go to Exposed Options > check "Exposed items per page"

Comment: Is it possible to apply this to the default search results somehow?

Comment: I don't know, but the Search API module says it has "the ability to use the Views module for displaying search results" ... so may be worth looking into.